# java_home on centos

Tags: centos, environment-variables

I am using a centos virtual machine instance.
I have edited the /root/.bash_profile and set the JAVA_HOME path.

the changes are saved but when I type echo $JAVA_HOME, the command executes but show nothing.

typing which java shows some other folder, which doesnt exist.

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Command from .bash_profile will be applied where user log on, try to logoff and logon or restart computer.

Do you use SUN JDK or Open JDK ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also set JAVA_HOME by creating a shell script in /etc/profile.d/ directory, for example:

create file: /etc/profile.d/java.sh

with following contents:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Please note that directory should target place were java was installed. One above should be proper when you install Oracle JDK.

Following variables will be set during system start.